# Как в рекурсии удалось подсчитать сумму?

Tags: javascript

```js
let company = { // тот же самый объект, сжатый для краткости
  sales: [{name: 'John', salary: 1000}, {name: 'Alice', salary: 600 }],
  development: {
    sites: [{name: 'Peter', salary: 2000}, {name: 'Alex', salary: 1800 }],
    internals: [{name: 'Jack', salary: 1300}]
  }
};

// Функция для подсчёта суммы зарплат
function sumSalaries(department) {
  if (Array.isArray(department)) { // случай (1)
    return department.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current.salary, 0); // сумма элементов массива
  } else { // случай (2)
    let sum = 0;
    for (let subdep of Object.values(department)) {
      sum += sumSalaries(subdep); // рекурсивно вызывается для подотделов, суммируя результаты
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

console.log(sumSalaries(company));
```

1. запускаем функцию **sumSalaries(company)**
2. Выполнится условие **else** и будет такой результат
3. объект **sales** будет :

   ```
   [{name: 'John', salary: 1000}, {name: 'Alice', salary: 600 }],
   ```
4. объект development будет:

   ```
   development: {
       sites: [{name: 'Peter', salary: 2000}, {name: 'Alex', salary: 1800 }],
       internals: [{name: 'Jack', salary: 1300}]
   }
   ```
5. **sales** будет массивом, условие **if** верно, значит код выполнится получим число
6. **development** условие **if ложно**, значит выполнится код **else**
7. И тут я перестал понимать как мы получим сумму всех чисел, если произошло ветвление **sales идет в if, development идет else ?**
8. Продолжаю дальше: результат **if** передается **sum**, т.к. при первом вызове функции выполняется условие **else**, где  будет **sum += sumSalaries(subdep);**
9. **development**, как мы помним, пошел **else** тут будет **sum += sumSalaries(subdep);** где код снова вызовется только уже пойдет в **if** и результат кода вернется sum
10. Код уходит из цикла и функция возвращает **sum**

Comment: так комментарии же написаны

Comment: @Grundy смотрите пункт 7

Comment: @Stranger in the Q прошу отзовитесь пожалуйста

Comment: _как мы получим сумму всех чисел если произошло ветвление sales идет в if, development идет else ?_ - каждая из веток возвращает результат

Comment: ты в рассуждениях пропустил, что сначала ты передаешь `company`, это значит, что ты попадаешь в цикл `for (let subdep of Object.values(department)) {` - внутри которого и складываешь суммы по отделам. Именно об этом и написано в комментарии в коде